# How do efficiently cache shortest path calculations with binary nodes?

Tags: optimization, memory, lua, path-finding

I'm working on a game and in that game I need a way to find the shortest between two nodes in a scene.

The actual path finding is fine, we're using A* for this.
The speed at which it computes is fine for the most part, but being that it is for an optimized form of sound "diffraction"(think R6Siege) we don't want much real-time computation at all. Especially when this will be required so frequently.

So this is what it currently looks like finding the shortest route between the source and the listener.

[image]

Green Nodes = Path Nodes

Blue Nodes = "Closed" Path Nodes

Red = Breachable wall

In this example you can see that there is a red wall to the right of the room. 
The are closed because the wall is in-tact, but if there were to be an explosion and one of those nodes were within the radius of the explosion, that node would be opened.

So in that case the shortest path may look something like this if that node was opened.

[image]

Likewise, if you repaired the wall, the node may be closed again.

**Now here lies our problem. I'm in need of a way to "cache" the shortest routes between two nodes, for every node configuration**. Only nodes on walls will be able to be closed, but even then if we have a ton of walls that can be breached, having a cache/lookup table for every combination of those nodes being opened/closed, that just seems like an enormous amount of data/memory and it seems very silly or even impossible to take a brute approach like that.

How do you guys recommend doing this? Some way to compress the data so the potential memory in storing a cache table for every configuration wouldn't be quite as high? Some fancy data structures ?

I'm not a beginner to game development necessarily but I am rather new to this sort of problem.

Thank you! :)